# Remove hidden midpoint character from json string

Tags: php, json, character, hidden, jsondecoder

Sending an API request I get a json string as answer which seems to include a hidden character, a midpoint [·]. In my ATOM editor the character is not visible but trying to remove the character after the midpoint results in no visible action, which indicates that it then removed the midpoint.

The consequence of the problem that transforming the json string to a PHP array results in array having value NULL.

**Question:**

What is the most straightforward way to remove the hidden character?
Should I search for the character and simply cut that character out of the string?

I understand that potentially the best would be to find the root-cause of why the midpoint got there, but I cannot find the root-cause.

**Investigation and outcomes:**

Comparing [$body1] and [body2] in https://www.diffchecker.com/, it shows:

```
[$body1] ·'{"columns":"test"}'
[$body1] '{"columns":"test"}'
```

---

This test shows that I do in fact have a hidden character.
It might not work in your environment to test since the hidden character probably is removed by copy/paste.

```
$body1 = '{"columns":"test"}'; // Hidden character.
$body2 = '{"columns":"test"}'; // Removed hidden character.
$body3 = '{"columns":"test"}'; // Same as body2.

var_dump(json_decode($body2, true));

if($body1 == $body2) {
    echo 'Content the same';
} else
    echo 'Content differs';
```

Result:

```
Content differs
```

**Checking string length of the body strings.**

```
echo strlen($body1) . "\n";
echo strlen($body2) . "\n";
echo strlen($body3) . "\n";
```

Result:

```
21
18
18
```

Comment: can please elaborate the Hidden Character term? Did you mean character is not displaying on the screen?
try ```str_replace``` function if any character is creating issue while decoding JSON.

Comment: Do the hidden characters occur only at the start or it could be anywhere in the string?

Comment: I am just testing one scenario so the hidden character could be moving around, depending on the request. Currently I see that there are 3 characters that forms the midpoint character. Since it is in the start I can use [substr($array, 3] to remove the first 3 character, and then the solution works.

Comment: @ Arjun Singh That is correct, the the mentioned character is not visible on the screen.